# How I can do a POST request with RxJava2 and Retrofit2??

Tags: android, post, retrofit2, rx-java2

I'm trying to learn RxJava2 and Retrofit together and now, I know how to call to make GET requests. But I don't know how to do and POST, PUT... etc.

My AccountUserApi file is:

```
@GET(LiveDataApi.GET_USER)
    Flowable<HttpCustomRes<UserPostData>> getUserData(@Path("id") long userId);

...

@POST(LiveDataApi.POST_LOGIN)
    Flowable<HttpCustomRes<User>> loginUser(@Body @Field("user") String username, @Body @Field("password") String password);
```

For the manager I have:

```
    public class AccountUserManager {

        @Inject
        public AccountUserManager(){}

        public AccountUserApi getApi() {
            return HttpRetrofit.getInstance().getService(AccountUserApi.class);
        }

// THIS IS BAD :(
        public Flowable<User> loginUser(String username, String password){
            return getApi().loginUser(username, password).map(new Function<HttpCustomRes<User>, User>() {
                @Override
                public User apply(@NonNull HttpCustomRes<User> userPostDataHttpCustomRes) throws Exception {
                    if(userPostDataHttpCustomRes != null) {
                        return userPostDataHttpCustomRes.getData();
                    }else
                        return null;
                }
            });
        }

        public Flowable<UserPostData> getUserData(long userId){
            return getApi().getUserData(userId).map(new Function<HttpCustomRes<UserPostData>, UserPostData>() {
                @Override
                public UserPostData apply(@NonNull HttpCustomRes<UserPostData> userPostDataHttpCustomRes) throws Exception {
                    if(userPostDataHttpCustomRes != null) {
                        return userPostDataHttpCustomRes.getData();
                    }else
                        return null;
                }
            });
        }

        public Flowable<EmptyModel> setUserData(long userId, UserPostData userPostData){
            return getApi().setUserData(userId, userPostData).map(new Function<HttpCustomRes<EmptyModel>, EmptyModel>() {
                @Override
                public EmptyModel apply(@NonNull HttpCustomRes<EmptyModel> emptyModelHttpCustomRes) throws Exception {
                    if(emptyModelHttpCustomRes != null) {
                        return emptyModelHttpCustomRes.getData();
                    }else
                        return null;
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

How I can do a POST request with RxJava2 and Retrofit2? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I encourage you to use [retrolambda plugin](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda) in order to reduce the verbosity of the RxJava methods.

For the request, to make a POST request you have to send an object that represents the Body of the request. I think that what you are trying to achieve is:

```
@POST(LiveDataApi.POST_LOGIN)
Flowable<HttpCustomRes<User>> loginUser(@Body UserBody user);
```

And the UserBody object, I imagine that would be something like:

```
class UserBody {
   private final String user;
   private final String password;

   UserBody(String user, String password) {
       this.user = user;
       this.password = password;
   }
}
```

I recommend you to read the [Retrofit docs](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) where is better explained how to make the proper requests.